Should we provide an explicit close button in the dialog, to play well with gesture navigation?
Few years back, when Android is still using 3 buttons navigation, it makes sense not providing an explicit closed button for dialog.
3 buttons navigation

There are 2 ways to close the dialog

Tap on the back button (Circled in red)
Tap anywhere outside the dialog


However, when using the new gesture navigation, it isn't clear on how to close the dialog.
Gesture navigation

There is only 1 obvious way (maybe not obvious to some users) to close the dialog

Tap anywhere outside the dialog

Another non-obvious way, to swipe at the left edge.
Do you think, should we provide a "x" button at top left, or an "OK" button at bottom right, to enable users to close the dialog, in an easy way?

I had the same problem with a modal window that closed when clicking outside the window, but there were some users who didn't understand it and couldn't find a way to close the modal. I chose as a solution to place a ✖️ symbol outside the window without any added action, in this way whoever clicked outside the window, whether on the symbol or anywhere else, closed the window.
